# axios.post doesn't seem to work?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, http-post, axios

Maybe I am just not using axios correctly but I currently have a react front-end and node.js back end.

I am trying to POST to my api endpoint "/api/:id/addItem" but nothing is logging when making the request.

Here is my code:

ListForm component ->

```
import React from 'react';
import * as helpers from '../helpers';

class ListForm extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: ''
  }

  handSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    helpers.addItem(this.props.currentUser.googleId, this.state.value);

    this.setState({value: ''});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input type="text"
          value={this.state.value}
          onChange={e => this.setState({value: e.target.value})}
        />
        <button>Add item</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default ListForm;
```

Routes ->

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = require('../models/userSchema');

module.exports = (app) => {
  app.post('/api/:id/addItem', (req, res) => {
    console.log('HEY!');
  });
};
```

helpers.js ->

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const fetchUser = async () => {
  const resp = await axios.get('/api/current_user');

  return resp.data;
}

export const addItem = async (id, newItem) => {
  const resp = await axios.post("/api/" + id + "/addItem", newItem);

  return resp.data;
}
```

Package.json to show forwarding requests->

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": {
    "/auth/google": {
      "target": "http://localhost:5000"
    },
    "/api/*": {
      "target": "http://localhost:5000"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.17.1",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.17"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Comment: your function is named `handSubmit` but you are calling `this.handleSubmit`

Comment: your server only handle for post `/api/addItem` so obviously return nothing when you post `/api/:id/addItem`

Comment: Sorry I left that in there when I was just trying to confirm the post was working. Updated now

Comment: `package.json` show that you will redirect to handle `/api/*` in server `http://localhost:5000`. Do you check it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue here is with `newItem` , its not `json` it's just simple `value`

```
axios.post("/api/" + id + "/addItem", newItem);
```

It should be like :

```
axios.post("/api/" + id + "/addItem", {value : newItem});
```

Or pass json from `addItem` :

```
helpers.addItem(this.props.currentUser.googleId, this_should_be_json );
```